# Gnome site does not see Gnome installed on 19.04

Tags: gnome, 19.04

Whenever I go to a Gnome website when I am using a 19.04 desktop, I get the message that Gnome does not appear to be installed. Is there anything I need to do in Ubuntu to eliminate this message or is it a signal that something is wrong with the Gnome installation on my system?

Comment: Maybe the browser you're using makes a difference... also, can you give an example of a "gnome website"? I'm not using gnome, and when I go to gnome.org I don't get that warning...

Comment: Which browser, which website? Screenshot of the message?